# What's the issue with my sequential lookup in Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula

I have two sets of text data in Google Sheets, and I need to find out which rows are not covered by the other.

```
Col A:
john      
bob
mary

Col B:
mary
jim
john
```

What I thought I could do is do some kind of lookup- if A1 is in B, then it would return TRUE, and I could just sort/filter by T/F (so results for Col A would be T, F, T respectively) But I'm a complete idiot when it comes to sheets, and I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
=IF((LOOKUP A2, B1:B10), TRUE)
```

Any ideas? Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use match function like below-

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$3,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ARRAYFORMAULA` with `OR`:

```
=ArrayFormula(OR(A1=$B$1:$B$3))
```

[image]